# Display the image attachment of URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the actual image of an attachment, not the url of the attachment.  I am using this code but it is displaying the url:

```
 <?php
 $argsThumb = array(
     'order'       => 'ASC',
     'post_type'   => 'attachment',
     'post_parent' => $post->ID,
     'post_status' => null
 );
 $attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
 if ($attachments) {
     foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
         echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, false, false); 
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

```
 <?php
 $argsThumb = array(
     'order'       => 'ASC',
     'post_type'   => 'attachment',
     'post_parent' => $post->ID,
     'post_status' => null
 );
 $attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
 if ($attachments) {
     foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
         echo "<img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, false, false) . "' />"; 
     }
 }
 ?>
```